# Creating an image grid with data sideview with HTML/CSS/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a webpage that loads images from a search query. I need to load the images similar to the style shown below. I also need a side box that shows the metadata of the selected image. How can I go about this?

[image]

Comment: Your question is too broad. What specifically are you having trouble with? The Mosaic layout? Identifying the image clicked on? Retrieving the meta data? Display in the meta data? This list goes on. Any one of those questions could be a StackOverflow question on its own. Please remember StackOverflow is **not** a code writing service. It is designed for answering questions with a fairly narrow scope. Equally important, what have you tried so far? What worked and what didn't?